# How can I create a Pivot Table and name it using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm playing around with this small piece of code.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Personnel&Facilities Detail!R3C1:R105279C21", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14 _
    ).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Corporate Communications!R1C1", _
    TableName:="PivotTable9", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

I'm trying to loop through a range of cells and create a bunch of pivots based on some data sets that I have.  I have the loop working fine and I recorded a Macro that should do what I want.  The thing that I can't figure out is the naming convention of the pivot tables.  It seems to increment by 1 each time I turn on the Macro Recorder and click through the sequence of events.  I'm pretty sure the problem is here:

TableName:="PivotTable9"

I tried to clear the cache of the pivot tables to reset the table name, but that didn't work.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you're creating multiple pivot tables based on the same pivot cache. The problem to me looks like you're attempting to create each pivot table on top of the previously created table on the same worksheet at the same cell. Try moving `TableDestination` with each loop iteration (possibly the easiest is a new worksheet for each PT). Excel will automatically increment your pivot table names if your `TableName` already exists. So you must also create a unique name for each PT in each iteration of your loop.

Comment: It may be what you said.  Can you post some sample code?  I've tried a bunch of things and nothing is working for me.  I can do this on another machine using Excel 2003.  I don't know why Excel 2010 can't handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The process you're looking for is to establish each part of a `PivotTable` separately. It makes it much easier to track down problems and errors as they occur. The code example below show how to set up a common `PivotCache` and then create a number of `PivotTables` from that single, common cache.

There are many things missing from this example, such as checks for worksheets that exist with the same name, upper and lower limits to the number of pivots that can be created, plus adding fields to each of the tables.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim dataArea As Range
    'Set dataArea = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Personnel&Facilities Detail").Range("A3:U105279")
    Set dataArea = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A1:L250")
    CreateAllPivots dataArea, 5
End Sub

Sub CreateAllPivots(ByRef dataArea As Range, ByVal numPivots As Integer)
    '--- given an input range and the number of Pivot Tables to create,
    '    this sub creates a single, common Pivot Cache and then new
    '    Pivot Tables (each on its own worksheet)

    '--- perform any parameter checks, such as numPivots > 0

    '--- create the common pivot cache for all tables
    Dim ptWB As Workbook
    Dim ptCache As PivotCache
    Set ptWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ptCache = ptWB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                          SourceData:=dataArea, _
                                          Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    '--- define the base name of the PT worksheets
    Dim ptName As String
    Dim ptSheetName As String
    ptName = "CorpCommPT"
    ptSheetName = "Corp Communications - "

    '--- set up all the pivot tables
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ptSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newPTName As String
    Dim thisPivot As PivotTable
    For i = 1 To numPivots
        Set ptSheet = ptWB.Sheets.Add
        ptSheet.Name = ptSheetName & i
        newPTName = ptName & i
        Set thisPivot = ptCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ptSheet.Range("A1"), _
                                                 TableName:=newPTName, _
                                                 DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
        '--- potentially set up the pivot fields for the new table here
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a beautiful thing!  Thanks.  In addition, I found this link to be helpful.



http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/pivot-tables-examples/